# Is it possible to connect MySQL to XAMPP log in, which can cause My SQL server away?

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine, authentication

In Unity, I passed my username and password to Login.php and 'My SQL Server away' occurred.
I set it up as follows.

php.ini

```
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filezie = 750M
max_execution_time = 1200
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000 M
max_allowed_packet = 200M
```

phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

+add

```
$cfg ['ExecTimeLimit'] = 6000;
```

+add
    my.ini

```
innodb_look_wait_timeout=600
```

If I entered localhost: 8080 / escape_room / Login.php in the web address, it takes a long time for the result screen to appear.
I would like to ask for advice on this matter.

+Login.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost:8080";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbName="escape_room";
$user_username = $_POST['Input_user'];
$user_password = $_POST['Input_pass'];
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
if(!$conn){
    die("Cound not Connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT pass FROM escape_room WHERE user = '".$user_username."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//Get the result and confirm login 
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($numrows == 0)
{
    die("ID does not exist \n");
}
else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if($row['pass'] == $user_password){ 
            echo "login success";
            echo $row['pass'];  
        }else{
            echo "password incorrect";
            echo "password is =". $row['pass'];
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Errors are as follows.

```
mysqli :: _construct(): MySQLserver has gone away
mysqli :: _construct(): Error While reading greeting packet PID=7572
mysqli :: _construct(): (HY000/2006) : MySQL server has gone away
```

Comment: $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName, $port);

Even though I changed, I get the same error.

Comment: I set 8080 as $ port. Should I set the mysql port to 3306?

Comment: The port 80 is being used by the kernel in my computer. This problem is too difficult for me. Thank you.

Comment: Wow. !!!!!!!!! Thank you so much!!!!!!! I have received great grace from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `8080` is the port your apache is configured to run on, not mysql. You should remove that from your connection string:

```
$servername = "localhost";
```

If you are running it on a custom port you should pass it in as the fifth parameter of the connection call.

Also `127.0.0.1` may work better for you than `localhost`.